# Debugging a factorial function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the code that I need to debug.

I have done part of the debug already but it still missing something that I don't understand and now I'm stuck.

```
def factorial(n):

  """Calculate the factorial of the given value and return the result.

    The factorial of n is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to n.
    This function does not support negative values - if a negative value is given, this function just returns 1.

    Arguments:
   n -- A positive integer
"""
  result = n
  while n != 0:
    result = result * n
    n -= 1
    return result

# Calculate factorial for the first four integers
for i in range(1, 5):
  print('Factorial of', i, 'is', factorial(i))
```

The output should be:

```
Factorial of 1 is 1 

Factorial of 2 is 2

Factorial of 3 is 6

Factorial of 4 is 24
```

But the current output is:

```
Factorial of 1 is 1

Factorial of 2 is 4

Factorial of 3 is 9

Factorial of 4 is 16
```

Comment: 1/ You start by multiplying n by itself, not by n-1 and 2/ you return at the end of the first loop... Try to run the code by hand with pencil and paper and you'll see what happens.

Comment: ```result = result * n```. This is because ```return``` ends the function. After the function has ended, it can't do anything unless you call it again

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read about [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). You can also use [Python-Tutor](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit) which helps to visualize the execution of the code step-by-step.

Answer (score 0):

Few corrections in your code:

1. Move `return` outside `while` loop. Or else, once the `return` statement is encountered, the function ends.
2. You are assigning `result=n`. But in your while loop, you are doing `result=result*n`. In short, you are squaring `n`, then returning `n`.
3. Assign `result` as 1, instead of `n`:

```
def factorial(n):

  """Calculate the factorial of the given value and return the result.

    The factorial of n is the product of all positive integers less than or equal to n.
    This function does not support negative values - if a negative value is given, this function just returns 1.

    Arguments:
   n -- A positive integer
"""
  result=1
  while n != 0:
    result*= n
    n -= 1
  return result
```

Output:

```
Factorial of 1 is 1
Factorial of 2 is 2
Factorial of 3 is 6
Factorial of 4 is 24
```